# List All Text Files in a Directory with more than 100 Lines using PowerShell

Tags: list, powershell, text, lines

Hello I'm PowerShell beginner. I'm looking for a script which finds and list all text files in a directory (`*.TXT`) with more than 100 lines.

This code show max and min number of lines in a directory but doesn't list files with min or max number of lines.

```
dir . -filter "*.txt" -Recurse -name | foreach{(GC $_).Count} | measure-object -sum -max -min
```

Comment: You need to do a minimum effort to find out how to recursively list files in a directory, then open these files and find the newline characters. Do your homework, post code and THEN scream for help.

Comment: As @AdmiralAdama implicitly points out, you also need to determine if a file contains text exclusively. Which encoding is acceptable, ASCII, UTF-8...? Do files such as HTML, XML, SVG... count as text files? or should you fall back on file extensions?

Comment: [starting point](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/10/09/use-a-powershell-cmdlet-to-count-files-words-and-lines.aspx)

Comment: See http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/02/03/list-files-in-folders-and-subfolders-with-powershell.aspx for listing files.

Comment: Thanks Mr Google: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/10/09/use-a-powershell-cmdlet-to-count-files-words-and-lines.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close.  You had the correct commandlet (`Measure-Object`); you simply needed to use the `-Line` parameter, and then use `Where-Object`.  Note the use of `Select-Object` with `-ExpandProperty`.  That is what turns a collection of TextMeasureInfo objects into a collection of integers.  This worked for me:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse |
    Where-Object {
        (Get-Content $_.FullName |
         Measure-Object -Line |
         Select-Object -ExpandProperty Lines) -gt 100
    }
```

If you want to fit it on one line and use aliases, this is the equivalent:

```
dir . -filter "*.txt" -Recurse | ? {(gc $_.FullName | Measure -Line | Select -Expand Lines) -gt 100 }
```

And you also asked about finding files that have a minimum and maximum number of lines.  I wouldn't recommend writing that in one line, since it becomes unreadable.  To do it, you need an intermediate variable inside the `Where-Object` ScriptBlock:

```
$minLines = 10
$maxLines = 200

Get-ChildItem . -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse |
    Where-Object {
        $numLines = Get-Content $_.FullName |
            Measure-Object -Line |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty Lines
        if (($numLines -gt $minLines) -and ($numLines -lt $maxLines)) {
            return $_
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This work really good. One more question. Let's say that instead of using hard number (100 lines) I would like to list .txt files with minimum and maximum number of lines.

Comment: You're welcome.  I've updated my answer with your follow-up question.  Please mark my response as the answer to your question?

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, but for some reason second script doesn't work properly. I don't know why. I have in one directory hundreds of text files some of them has over 700 lines some just 4 or 5. Sometimes min or max criteria meet dozens of files with same number of lines. I tried to change $minLines to 1 and $maxLines to 1000, but for some reason it lists all text files in a folder.It would be probably more clear to list all files (if more than one) with minimum lines and than all files(if more than one) with max lines.Thank you for your help anyway.I will try to fix it by myself.

Comment: Probably at first in $minLines and $maxLines shuld be stored somehow maximum and minimum of all text files of a directory and then list file or files matching minimum number of lines and then maximum number of lines. But I may by wrong, because I'm just beginner in powershell scripting.